# Http status 415 Unsupported Media type error with JSON POST

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, http-status-code-415

I get the HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type error when I try to send a POST request to the server. `Content-Type: application/json` does not solve the problem. The get method works fine. I understand that it may be a matter of ManyToOne dependency, but I can't decide how to write a request.

Enity class:

```java
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "director")
    @Data
    public class Director {
        @Id
        @Column
        private int id;
    
        @Column
        private String name;
    
        @Column
        private String surname;
    
        @Column
        private String post;
    
        @Column
        private int numberPhone;
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "directorFromProjectActivities")
        @JsonManagedReference
        private List<ProjectActivities> projectActivitiesList;
```

RestController:

```java
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api")
    public class RestControllerDirector {
    import org.example.dao.IDao;
    import org.example.entity.Director;
    import org.example.services.IService;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
    import java.util.List;
        @PostMapping(value = "/director", consumes = {"*/*"})
        public void addDirector(@RequestBody Director director){
            dao.add(director);
        }
    }
```

JSON I'm sending a postman:

```json
    {
        "id": 100,
        "name": "Alex",
        "surname": "Round",
        "post": "HR",
        "numberPhone": 82171788
    }
```

dependence jackson:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.13.1</version>
</dependency>
```

How is it possible to solve this problem?

Comment: what media/type do you send in the header ? :)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is this line

@PostMapping(value = "/director", consumes = {"*/*"})
when i tried to recreate your situation it went on internal error you should either remove "consumes" entirely or write application/json in it and write that in postman as well

Comment: No `consumers = {"/"}` did not affect the operation of the program. I found out empirically that it's problem in @OneToMany. If i delete `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "directorFromProjectActivities")
        @JsonManagedReference
        private List<ProjectActivities> projectActivitiesList;`, then everything works. But, I still can't write JSON with proper deserialization when i have communication @OneToMany

Answer (score 0):

Try `consumes="application/*"`

I'll prefer to define cosumers data type using

`cosumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON`

or if it's support multiple type like json and XML by define:

`consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}`.

See more examples from [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#consumes).

Also, it's good practice to return HTTP status code 201 with a body on the successful creation of a resource (Director). The body can be information returned to the client back like id etc. Like

`return new ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).build()`

or with body

`return new ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(/** your response object here **/).build()`

Make sure add `produces` annotation just `consumes` on method `addDirector`.

Here is [ResponseEntity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) and [MediaType](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html) documentation.